# How to write this Anonymous C# method in VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, c#-to-vb.net

I need to spawn several background threads for the [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.ThreadPool.aspx) (my test store contains 6008 part numbers, and the individual threads would look up each part's barcode and description from the corporate database).

I am getting ideas from this post: [Wait for pooled threads to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/540078/153923)

I am interested in trying [JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar)'s answer without the WaitHandle (since it has a 64 thread limit), but I don't know how to duplicate his [QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) in this VB application:

```
public static void SpawnAndWait(IEnumerable<Action> actions)
{
    var list = actions.ToList();
    var handles = new ManualResetEvent[actions.Count()];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        handles[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var currentAction = list[i];
        var currentHandle = handles[i];
        Action wrappedAction = () => { try { currentAction(); } finally { currentHandle.Set(); } };
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => wrappedAction());
    }
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles);
}
```

How would `x => wrappedAction()` be written in VB?

It seems like a simple task, but I cannot find any information on how to convert it.

Below is a little VB stub I wrote, trying to get this working.

Using what someone found in [Invoke anonymous methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15556182/153923), I tried writing it different ways.

```
Private m_db As DatabaseHelper

Public Sub Test1(store As StoreLocation)
    For index As Integer = 0 To store.Parts.Count - 1
        Dim item As StorePart = store.Parts(index)
        Dim job As New Action(
            Sub()
              Dim lines As String() = m_db.GetDetails(store.ID, item.PartNumber)
              item.UPC = lines(0)
              item.Vendor = lines(1)
              item.Description = lines(2)
            End Sub
        )
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(job()) ' See 1.
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(job.Invoke()) ' See 2.
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(job) ' See 3.
    Next
End Sub
```

No, it does not compile.

1. Expression does not produce a value
2. Expression does not produce a value
3. Value of type 'System.Action' cannot be converted to 'System.Threading.WaitCallback'

This project compiles to .NET 4.0, so I can't really use 4.5 await features unless plugins are authorized for the corporate project.

Comment: Have you considered letting the [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) handle the threading details?

Comment: I'm not great at doing this stuff in my preferred C# language. Can you show me how to do it in VB?

Comment: As for syntax I'm pretty sure the translation from c# would be more like `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Function(x) job())`

Comment: Still shows squiggle under `job()` with **Expression does not produce a value**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would x => wrappedAction() be written in VB?

```
Well it is 

Sub(x) wrappedAction()
```

Although the `x` is irrelevant as it is not used, so you could use `Sub() wrappedAction()` instead

So something like this should do:

```
Public Shared Sub SpawnAndWait(ByVal actions As IEnumerable(Of Action))
    Dim list = actions.ToList()
    Dim [handles] = New ManualResetEvent(actions.Count() - 1){}
    For i = 0 To list.Count - 1
        [handles](i) = New ManualResetEvent(False)
        Dim currentAction = list(i)
        Dim currentHandle = [handles](i)
        Dim wrappedAction As Action = Sub()
            Try
                currentAction()
            Finally
                currentHandle.Set()
            End Try
        End Sub
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(x) wrappedAction())
    Next i
    WaitHandle.WaitAll([handles])
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The [WaitCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate is defined as

```vb
<ComVisibleAttribute(True)> _
Public Delegate Sub WaitCallback(state As Object)
```

So the correct syntax would be:

```vb
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(state As Object) wrappedAction())
```

```vb
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(state As Object) job())
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(state As Object) job.Invoke())
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(state As Object) job())
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the C# code, compiling it, then running the assembly through [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) and selecting VB as the output language, I got:

```
Public Shared Sub SpawnAndWait(ByVal actions As IEnumerable(Of System.Action))
    Dim list As List(Of System.Action) = actions.ToList(Of System.Action)()
    Dim handles(actions.Count(Of System.Action)()) As System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < list.Count
        handles(i) = New System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)
        Dim item As System.Action = list(i)
        Dim manualResetEvent As System.Threading.ManualResetEvent = handles(i)
        Dim action As System.Action = Sub()
        Try
            item()
        Finally
            manualResetEvent.[Set]()
        End Try
        End Sub
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(x As Object) action())
        i = i + 1
    End While
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles)
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a unique way of approaching it - and it works, too! :)

Comment: Actually, there a couple of mistakes in that code that you might want to mention to JustDecompile: 1. You can't use 'handles' as an identifier unless you enclose it in square brackets and 2. the array specifier on 'handles' needs to be reduced by 1 since VB arrays are declared using upper bound, not size (this is a critical error on the part of a decompiler).